# Additional functionality on the End node

Tags: django-viewflow, viewflow

There is a mixin,

```
class AaTaskRelationMixin(object):
    aa_task_comlete_function = None
```

that will be mixed to a flow. I want all flows in the end (when End node is activated) call a function in the attribute aa_task_complete_function

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler solution.

```
class AaTaskRelationMixin(object):

    aa_task_comlete_function = None

    aa_task_comlete = flow.Handler(
        handler=this.aa_task_comlete_function,
    ).Next(this.end)

    end = flow.End()
```